# Why does it keep looping at Would You Like To Try Again?

Tags: c#, console

Ok so I am trying to run this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ans;
    bool Operation = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Hello user, would you like to do maths today? Write yes or no.");
    ans = Console.ReadLine();
    ans.ToLower();
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again?");
        string answerFinal = Console.ReadLine();
        answerFinal.ToLower();

        if (answerFinal == "yep")
        {
            Operation = true;

        }
        else
        {
            Operation = false;
        }

    }
    while (Operation == true);
}
```

However, it keeps looping at Would You Like To Try Again if I keep pressing yes, any ideas why? I think it has to do with Try Catch, can someone tell me how to use them in this instance?

Answer (score 4):

```
ans.ToLower();
```

doesn't modify anything in `ans`, it returns a copy of `ans` as lowercase.  You need to do this:

```
ans = ans.ToLower();
```

For each time you use `.ToLower()`, like for `answerFinal`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the same variable here

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello user, would you like to do maths today? Write yes or no.");
ans = Console.ReadLine();
ans.ToLower();
```

and here

```
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Please select from one of the operations!");
Console.WriteLine("Either write Multiplication, Division, Addition or Subtraction.");

ans = Console.ReadLine();
ans.ToLower();
```

So by the time the do-while starts again, the value in `ans` has already changed and isn't yes any longer so it just goes to the last statement. Change the second part of the code to

```
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Please select from one of the operations!");
Console.WriteLine("Either write Multiplication, Division, Addition or Subtraction.");

string answer = Console.ReadLine();
answer = answer.ToLower();

if (answer == "multiplication")
{
    //other statements
```

Also, change

```
ans.ToLower();
```

to

```
ans = ans.ToLower();
```

and the same for the likes

Answer (score 1):

You assign your `ans` variable to a bunch of different values in your loop, none of them being "yes". Then when you come back into the `do` loop again you fail the first condition statement `if (ans == "yes")`. This will be false, causing you to keep skipping over that block of code, landing you right back to the "Would you like to try again" line.